# .keys() method not working on JSONObject eclipse

Tags: java, json

i am trying to use the .keys() method to get the name of JSON Object's 
the code im using is;

```
Iterator<String> keys = JSONObject.keys();
```

.keys() is underelined as red on eclipse, i dont know why, can any one help, thanks! -

[image]

I have JSON simple as an external library and have imported it, not sure what else to do

EDIT:

Here is more code;

```
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            FileReader testfile = new FileReader("test2.txt");
            Object obj = parser.parse(testfile); 
            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            JSONObject name = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("txt");
            String time = (String) name.get("name");
            JSONObject example2 = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("birth");
            System.out.println(example2);



        Iterator keys = example2 .keys(); <-- where the red line shows up
```

Second edit:
here are my imports.

```
 import java.io.FileReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
     import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
```

Comment: Show us json to understand the cause

Comment: What is example2? Paste more code and not as image.

Comment: @Lemonov it has been added

Comment: What is the error message? Try clean project, full recompile, etc. because your code should work.

Comment: That keys() is undefined for a JSON Object

Comment: Show us your import list. AFAICT only importing the wrong class(es) can explain your error.

Comment: @S.Piller okay added above

Comment: http://juliusdavies.ca/json-simple-1.1.1-javadocs/org/json/simple/JSONObject.html does not have a .keys method. You are mixing two different API. org.json.JSONObject is different from what you are using.

Comment: You probably want `keySet()`

Comment: What JSONParser do i use @S.Piller i am getting "org.json.simple.JSONObject cannot be cast to org.json.JSONObject" if i use simple's one

Comment: Normal. You can not replace a part of an API with a part of another. org.json.simple.JSONObject and org.json.JSONObject are completely different, so how the parser for org.json.simple.JSONObject could produce org.json.JSONObject ? Again, you are reading doc from one API while implementing another.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
  Iterator<String> keys = example2.keySet().iterator();
```

Answer (score 0):

With this artifact: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20170516

Use the following code:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject("{\"key\":\"value\"}");
for(Object o : obj.keys()) { ... }
```

It will work.

Do not mix API.